# how to get div id into php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I get this `id` into a PHP variable after submit a form? I need to pass the total value to a PHP variable. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>        
            <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>                 
            <td>
                <input class="form-control1" type='text' id='txt_totalprice' name='txt_totalprice[]'/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>     
</div>

Total: <div id="totalvalue">0</div>
```

Here is the script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#totalvalue').click(function() {
        $.post("package.php", { 
            id: $(this).attr('id') 
        }, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Which PHP variable? Or you want send the value in DIV with the ajax request?

Comment: Your code is already doing what you require. Just use `$_POST['id']` in your `package.php` page

Comment: yes i want to send div id value to php variable

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i didn't get post value in package.php

Comment: In that case check the console to see if the request was sent and if there were any errors

Comment: no error found in my code.i'm getting only the output is "totalvalue"

Comment: That's because you're getting the attribute id of that element instead of the value inside of it. Replace $(this).attr('id') with $(this).text(). Your code is working fine but you're not getting what you really want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the value between the div tags, not the ID, correct?

Change this:

```
id: $(this).attr('id')
```

To this:

```
id: $(this).text()
```

If you want to display the value on the page do this:

Create an empty div:

```
<div id="saved-value"></div>
```

Place it anywhere you want on the page.

Then change your jQuery:

```
}, function(response) {
    $('#saved-value').html(response);
});
```

Comment: thanks..its working..i have one doubt how to pass this id to same page?

Comment: You mean instead of using the alert? Like, how do you present the value to the user on the page?

Comment: Create an empty div on the page with a unique ID. For the sake of the example we'll call it "saved-value" - then instead of calling for the alert, (alert(response);) put the response into the #saved-value div. $('#saved-value').html(response);

Comment: instead of $.post("package.php",) variable store in same php page?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused about the question. "response" in jQuery is the response you're receiving from package.php

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the id value on your package.php Page.

```
   <?php 

     $_POST['id'];

    ?>
```

or you can just store the id in a new variable.

```
<?php 

$id = $_POST['id'] 
echo($id);
?>
```

if you arent sure if there are any values being sent by your post you  can use this.

```
<?php 

//This will help you since Post is an array.
 print_r($_POST) 

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your support..i already connected these coding.I want to store this variable in same page instead of package.php url.